# ¿Por qué si se vació un campo de texto, una función JSON sigue obteniendo el valor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Tengo la siguiente función para comprobar un dato metido en una caja de texto.

```
function obtenerSancionado () {

    var cedula = { rcedula: $("#ccedula").val() };

    $.post("./funciones_php_verificarSancion.php", cedula , function (respuesta) {

        if (respuesta.sancionado == 0) {

            alert("Este funcionario se encuentra disponible para la sanción");

        } else if (respuesta.sancionado == 1) {

            $("#ccedula").val("");
            alert("Este funcionario NO se encuentra disponible por estar sancionado");
            $("#ccedula").focus();

        } else if (respuesta.sancionado == 2) {

            alert("Este n\u00famero de C\u00e9dula no está registrado en la base de datos");
            $("#ccedula").focus();
            $("#ccedula").val("");

        } 

    }, "json" );

    $.post("./funciones_php_obtenerDatosBasicos.php", cedula , function (respuesta) {

        if (respuesta.pnombrex == 99999) {

            alert("Este n\u00famero de C\u00e9dula no está registrado en la base de datos");
            $("#ccedula").focus();
            $("#ccedula").val("");

        } else {

            // ejemplo modificado con el json devuelto
            $("#papellido").val(respuesta.papellidox);
            $("#sapellido").val(respuesta.sapellidox);
            $("#pnombre").val(respuesta.pnombrex);
            $("#snombre").val(respuesta.snombrex);
            $("#grados").val(respuesta.gradof);
            $("#valor_grados").val(respuesta.gradoc);
            $("#fascenso").val(respuesta.fult_ascenso);
            $("#cargo").val(respuesta.cargo);
            $("#ccedula").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#restablecer1").prop("hidden", false);

        }

    }, "json" );

}
```

Al hacer el primer llamado `JSON` este devolverá 3 estados: `0`, `1` y `2`.

En el caso de ser `1` borro el campo de texto y debería dejar de ejecutarse la función.

Ocurre que a pesar de ello, la cédula se guarda y se cumple el segundo `JSON` de la función, quedándome unos campos de texto lleno de los datos de la persona.

¿Cómo puedo evitar que pase eso?

Ya traté colocando a `cedula = null`.

Comment: Te refieres a que de todos modos ejecuta el segundo post?. Más específicamente el else del if del segundo post. Y quisieras que esto no sucediera?.

Comment: @aponcedeleonch ejecuta el 2do post, y no quiero que pase eso una vez se cumpla el 2do Else if, pues aunque el consigue registros (porque de esa cedula existen) ese valor no cumple con los requisitos que se validaron en el php

Comment: puedes añadir que lenguaje usas porque con solo json no queda nada claro

Comment: agregare el codigo PHP @Webserveis

Comment: @Victor-Random, acabo de editar tu pregunta formateando mejor el código. Las dos llamadas `Ajax` se ejecutan en el mismo momento, así que no hay nada que evite que la segunda sea ejecutada. Si quieres que la segunda se ejecute solamente cuando se cumplan ciertas condiciones deberías situarla dentro de una de las condiciones.

Comment: @ElChiniNet son ajax?, pero devuelven JSON xD. en fin. como podria hacerlo?

Comment: Sí, el método [post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) de `jQuery` es un `shorthand` de una llamada `Ajax` usando `POST` como método, lo que devuelva la llamada `Ajax` se define mediante el parámetro `dataType`. Para poderte responder debo conocer cuándo deseas que se ejecute el segundo `post` (el que llama a `funciones_php_obtenerDatosBasicos.php`).

Comment: @ElChiniNet lo solucione, meti la condicion de sancionador==0 en un solo IF y dentro de ellos todo el 2do post, gracias :) publica tu respuesta y te la valio. Modifique tambien el PHP para regresar 0 para ambos casos de que pueda ingresarse la cedula

Comment: Vale, ya entiendo lo que deseas hacer, voy a publicar la respuesta usando algunas buenas prácticas que te ayudarán.

Comment: @ElChiniNet muchas gracias :)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58215/discussion-between-elchininet-and-victor-random).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que las dos llamadas `Ajax` se ejecutan a la vez, por lo tanto no importa lo que devuelva la primera llamada, la segunda siempre se ejecutará. Para que la segunda se ejecute solo cuando ocurra una de las condiciones deberías ejecutar la segunda dentro de dicha condición.

Voy a reescribir tu código siguiendo algunas buenas prácticas que te ayudarán a que el mismo esté más optimizado y más ordenado:

```
function obtenerSancionado () {

    var cedulaInput = $("#ccedula");

    var cedula = { rcedula: cedulaInput.val() };

    var limpiarCedula = function () {

        cedulaInput.val("").focus();

    };

    var metodos = {

        "metodo0" : function () {

            alert("Este funcionario se encuentra disponible para la sanción");

            metodos.obtener();

        },

        "metodo1" : function () {

            alert("Este funcionario NO se encuentra disponible por estar sancionado");

            limpiarCedula();

        },

        "metodo2" : function () {

            alert("Este n\u00famero de C\u00e9dula no está registrado en la base de datos");

            limpiarCedula();

        },

        "metodo3" : function () {

            alert("Este n\u00famero de C\u00e9dula no está registrado en la base de datos");

            limpiarCedula();

        },

        "metodo4" : function () {

            // ejemplo modificado con el json devuelto
            $("#papellido").val(respuesta.papellidox);
            $("#sapellido").val(respuesta.sapellidox);
            $("#pnombre").val(respuesta.pnombrex);
            $("#snombre").val(respuesta.snombrex);
            $("#grados").val(respuesta.gradof);
            $("#valor_grados").val(respuesta.gradoc);
            $("#fascenso").val(respuesta.fult_ascenso);
            $("#cargo").val(respuesta.cargo);
            $("#ccedula").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#restablecer1").prop("hidden", false);

        },

        "obtener" : function () {

            //---Segunda llamada Ajax
            $.post("./funciones_php_obtenerDatosBasicos.php", cedula , function (respuesta) {

                metodos[respuesta.pnombrex == 99999 ? "metodo3" : "metodo4"]();

            }, "json" );

        }

    };

    //---Primera llamada Ajax
    $.post("./funciones_php_verificarSancion.php", cedula , function (respuesta) {

        metodos["metodo" + respuesta.sancionado]();

    }, "json" );

}
```

Te explico los cambios en tu código:

1. Si vas a utilizar el elemento `$("#ccedula")` muchas veces, lo mejor es [cachearlo](https://ttmm.io/tech/selector-caching-jquery/) en una variable.
2. Si vas a repetir las mismas líneas varias veces en tu código, lo mejor es situar estas líneas en una función y llamar a esta cada vez que lo necesites (esto lo he aplicado con la función `limpiarCedula` que lo que hace es limpiar el valor del input y darle foco al mismo).
3. En vez de crear varios `if` y `else if`, sitúa todos tus métodos dentro de un objeto y llama a estos métodos cuando sea necesario.
4. Uno de los métodos es la segunda llamada `Ajax` (le he situado como nombre al método, `obtener`). Cuando se llame al método `metodo0` se llama al método `obtener`, si no se llama al `metodo0` la segunda llamada `Ajax` nunca se ejecutará.

Answer (score 1):

```
else if(respuesta.sancionado==1)
{
    $('#ccedula').val("");
    alert("Este funcionario NO se encuentra disponible por estar sancionado");
    $("#ccedula").focus();
    return;
}
```

Tambien podrias guardar "respuesta" en una var y antes del segundo json preguntar si respuesta !=1 que se ejecute el segundo $.post

Comment: Donde declaro esa variable?, la puse dentro del post y me da error porque no esta definida

Comment: Hola Gerardo, situar un `return` dentro de una de las condiciones de la primera llamada `Ajax` no evitará que se ejecute la segunda llamada `Ajax`. Observa que esos `if` / `else` están dentro de una función anónima que es llamada cuando se recibe la respuesta del servidor de la primera llamada.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que veo de tu código sólo quieres que se guarden los datos si `respuesta.sancionado == 0` entonces lo que podrías hacer es meter tu segundo post dentro de esa condición. Es decir, un post dentro de otro post. Entonces el código se vería algo así.

```
function obtenerSancionado () {

    var cedula = { rcedula: $("#ccedula").val() };

    $.post("./funciones_php_verificarSancion.php", cedula , function (respuesta) {

        if (respuesta.sancionado == 0) {

            alert("Este funcionario se encuentra disponible para la sanción");

            $.post("./funciones_php_obtenerDatosBasicos.php", cedula , function (respuesta) {

                if (respuesta.pnombrex == 99999) {

                    alert("Este n\u00famero de C\u00e9dula no está registrado en la base de datos");
                    $("#ccedula").focus();
                    $("#ccedula").val("");

                } else {

                    // ejemplo modificado con el json devuelto
                    $("#papellido").val(respuesta.papellidox);
                    $("#sapellido").val(respuesta.sapellidox);
                    $("#pnombre").val(respuesta.pnombrex);
                    $("#snombre").val(respuesta.snombrex);
                    $("#grados").val(respuesta.gradof);
                    $("#valor_grados").val(respuesta.gradoc);
                    $("#fascenso").val(respuesta.fult_ascenso);
                    $("#cargo").val(respuesta.cargo);
                    $("#ccedula").prop("disabled", true);
                    $("#restablecer1").prop("hidden", false);

                }

            }, "json" );

        } else if (respuesta.sancionado == 1) {

            $("#ccedula").val("");
            alert("Este funcionario NO se encuentra disponible por estar sancionado");
            $("#ccedula").focus();

        } else if (respuesta.sancionado == 2) {

            alert("Este n\u00famero de C\u00e9dula no está registrado en la base de datos");
            $("#ccedula").focus();
            $("#ccedula").val("");

        } 

    }, "json" );
}
```

Pero no sé si ese sea el comportamiento que estás esperando de tu código.

Comment: Lo unico que esta mal, es el sancionado == 2, ocurre que 0 y 2 devolvian lo siguiente: 0= el usuario NO tiene NINGUNA sancion, 2 el usuario TIENE  sanciones pero NO activas y 1 SI TIENE. ASi que puedes borrar el if de sancionado 2